# GitHub file size limit exceeded by React app static assets when deploying to Github Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

I am attempting to deploy my React app to github pages by:

1. Pushing updates to Github
2. Running `npm run deploy`

But I get the following error:

```
remote: warning: File static/media/db.bbef9ce0.gif is 55.87 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB                   
remote: warning: File static/media/website.a612b8be.gif is 73.98 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB              
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.        
remote: error: Trace: 5481bd86db186efed30eeeba2bbe31cb        
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.        
remote: error: File static/media/auto.6863815e.gif is 220.17 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB        
To github.com:markoelez/personal_website.git
 ! [remote rejected] gh-pages -> gh-pages (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to   'git@github.com:markoelez/personal_website.git'

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! personal_website@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the personal_website@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The files in question are `gifs` that I have excluded from my git commits by adding their directory `/src/assets` to my `.gitignore` file but for some reason they are causing the deployment to fail. I am able to push them to github without problem. How do I fix this?

> Update: So I tried using `git lfs` but I ended up running into the same error. Is there any way to configure `git lfs` to work with an npm deployment?

Comment: are they imported somewhere in your code?

Comment: @zynkn yes and I tried using `git lfs` to see if that would make things work with `npm` but it didn't help

Comment: NPM is irrelevant here, it's just a proxy to your own `deploy` script. Even if you've ignored these assets in your main branch, when deploying to the `gh-pages` branch, you're probably pushing everything since it needs all the final built files anyway.